# "Company is" or "Company are"?

Tags: data-is-are

I'm not sure if "is" or "are" would be correct. I've written what I'm trying to say in 2 different ways; one being option A and the other being option B.

**Option A:**
'What is the *name of the company?*
*The name of the company is*....'

Or

**Option B:**
'What are the *name of the company?*
*The name of the company* are...'

Comment: Partly a UK/US thing.

Comment: The other way ... "Company ABC is hiring" for US but "Company ABC are hiring" for UK.  In this example, "Company ABC" is the subject.  In your example, "Name" is the subject, so on both sides of the Atlantic we use "is".

Comment: 'Name' takes singular agreement. But this question is off-topic on ELU, Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those two options.

Option C) **What** is the name of the company?

You have to use "is" because an specific company got a single name.

According to Cambridge Dictionary

> **[who](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/who)**
>
> used especially in questions as the subject or object of a verb, when
> asking which **person or people**, or when asking what someone's name is

A company is not a person is a construct. A something, not a someone.

> [**what**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what)
>
> used to ask for information about people or **things**

Comment: I think "name of company" is being used in the original post as a placeholder for the actual name of a company, not as the literal phrase "the name of the company". I.e. the question is asking about sentences like "Who is/are Stack Exchange?"

Comment: @sumelic I got your point. Then it's a duplicated one as jejorda2 pointed

Answer (score 0):

If you swap out *company* for *business*, you wouldn't say *The business are*. That seems wrong, but *the business is* makes more sense. So *the company is* seems to be the preferred when I think about it.

Comment: I agree.  If the OP's sentences are the beginning of a paragraph or statement, they  should be "What is the name of the company?  *The* name of the company is...."   Suppose the company referred to is "General Eccentric".  You could write "The name of the company is General Eccentric" (with *The* before *name*), or "General Eccentric is the name of the company" (with no *the* before the actual name).